# timeout for repeated service calls in angular js

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I making list of service calls, like approximately 1000 calls.

i need to wait for some time(1s) each service call. can any one help me how can maintain timeout in angular js.

my code is:

```
   myArray.forEach(function(item){
      myService.getCall(itemNeedSend,function(){
         $timeout(function(){
              success call back
          },1000)

         },
     function(error){
       error call back here
     })
   })
```

I tried this one but is not working. can any one help me.

Comment: Are you trying to cut the request after 1 second if it didn't succeed yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you chain your promises, you can get it to work:

```
var promise = $timeout(function() {}, 1000);
myArray.forEach(function(item){
   var promise2 = myService.getCall(itemNeedSend,
       function(){ }, 
       function(error) { });
   promise2.then(promise);
   promise = $timeout(function() {}, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Hi @pixelbits, myArray Length is more than 1000, is it work fine?